# Get the ID from URL and select it from the database

Tags: python, django, view

I have `Post`. In the index page, I show all of them, ordering by `created_at`, as it shows in here:

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'blog/index.html'

    def get(self, request):
    return render (request, self.template_name, {
        'posts': Post.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    })
```

I've created a view that I intend to redirect to another page, showing the whole Post. This is the url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name = 'index'),
    url(r'^categories/$', views.CategoriesView.as_view(), name = 'categories'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.Post.as_view(), name = 'post')
]
```

and the view for such:

```
class Post(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'post.html'

    def get(self, request):
    id = request.GET.get('id', '')

    return render(request, self.template_name, {
        'post': get_object_or_404(Post, pk = id) 
    })
```

But then I am getting the error:

> **AttributeError at /**
>
> type object 'Post' has no attribute 'objects'.

Comment: You should use a DetailView for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't name both your view and model the same! Call it `PostView`, for example and the problem will be solved:

```
class PostView(TemplateView):
    ...
```

and

```
url(r'^post/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.PostView.as_view(), name = 'post')
```

You are also passing the `id` argument using URL rerouting; not through `GET`. Change the method signature to:

```
def get(self, request, id):
```

and use the `id` variable directly.

Comment: Great, the error has changed. Now, it says `get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'`. Probably just the way to retrieve the parameter from URL.

Comment: @GabrielMFernandes Yes, this is an unrelated error but see my updated answer.

Comment: The errors are gone, now I just need to figure out how to display the post, it's not displaying. Thank you.

Comment: The cause was imbecile. I put the `block` name differently from the `base.html`.